# How to automatically adjust tick label sizes so they don't overlap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a simple heatmap for a 50-by-100 matrix and wish to adjust the y-axis tick label sizes.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import random
    Nc=  100
    Nr=50
    
    M=np.random.rand(Nr,Nc)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(M,aspect='auto')
    
    ax.set_yticks(range(Nr))
    labels=[str(i) for i in range(Nr)]
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=6)
    
    plt.show()
```

This is "satisfactory" for my purposes insofar as the y-axis tick labels, while small in size, don't overlap.

In the program where I'll be using this, Nr may vary between 5 and 60 and the labels will consist of short two-character strings, e.g. 'A1', 'B3', etc. I'd like to adapt the code so that the fontsize is determined automatically so that the y-axis tick labels don't overlap. The actual size isn't important--I just don't want overlap. For example, if `Nr=30`, overlap starts when fontsize reaches about 11. When `Nr` is small, the fontsize should be no greater than 12, say. Because the labels are only two-character strings, I'd prefer not to simply rotate them.

Comment: Something like fontsize = figwidth * 72 / Nr / 3 (scale by 0.9 to account for the size of the axes relative to the figure) ?

Comment: @JodyKlymak --   That's the sort of approach I'm looking for. It's that scaling factor that I have to fine-tune.